# inherited friendship

Tags: c++

now before you guys start raging, here me out. Yes, i recognize that it is actually intended for friendship to not be inherited, i'm just trying to find some way to get something similar to it. Here is my situation (no real code, just theory). i'm working on a simple abstract game engine framework, and at first, i was just going to do the straightforward object oriented/ inheritance approach of breaking object types down. Now, it sounded really nice on paper, taking entities and breaking them into subcategories of physics, animated, and unmoving scenary and all it's subcategories. This however, became a hazardous, difficult to work with mess of entirely different objects and quite a bit of dangerous casting that could easily cause problems should i miss on something i needed to enforce instead of the compiler, which is always a good sign that there is a better solution.

So, I propose a different method of abstractly representing objects. I wish for there to be one entity class that all entities derive from which contain a vector, or some other dynamically growable array that works best, That will contain objects i'd call behaviors. The behaviors would be updated after a specified amount of time, which will affect the members of the object specified.  Here are some examples.

```
class Force : behavior;               
/*this would be a force, added to the behavior list and apply a constant 
acceleration vector to the object until removed from the behavior list. (or
it's lifetime is exhausted) */

class attackThought : behavior;  
/* For an ai, this would change how it reacts to a scenario by replacing or
even adding actions that it should perform given the change in position
or environment at update.*/

class animation : behavior;
/* You could create an animation, specify the animation that it is to perform, 
add it to the behavior list, and during the time update, it will adjust the 
vertex buffer accordingly, removing itself from the list when the animation
is done */
```

The problem is, i want to derive from a base behavior class, that implements some of it's virtual functions in different ways that will mostly change private members of the entity objects, (such as an objects vertex buffer). i don't want to have to manipulate too much of the basic entity code so that it can, (for the most part), be treated similarly to other objects, I only want their behaviors to be entirely manipulable/derivable. can anyone think of a way to make this system work in c++, cause i think it might be really cool :P.

btw, by way of friendship, i mean the base class behavior friending some derived entity class which can effect it's private members. For example, let's say i have a model class that derives from entity, and i want to friend a derived class of behavior called animation, and then later derive a class from model to a more specific type of object for some reason, how can an animation object manipulate the private members of this new model deriving object.

or can it? opinions on how viable this approach might be are also welcome, (as long as they actually contain critcism).

Comment: If you want attributes to be manipulated in all possible ways by a classes that you haven't yet thought of then shouldn't they be public rather than private? I think that would solve your issue.

Comment: maybe, but there just seems to be this horrible vibe i always get when something isn't encapsulated entirely, like i'm not using classes correctly. it's the same type of vibe i get dynamic casting objects and calling there members, like it will cause problems when making large-scale changes to a framework. in this scenario, would you think leaving the entity members public would cause problems later?

Comment: or wait not to a framework, to the objects connected to the framework. never change the framework, that's the point of a framework...

Comment: You're absolutely right that your not encapsulating things entirely. Making variables public reduces encapsulation in much the same way that having unlimited (and uncontrolled) friends would reduce encapsulation. If you want to increase encapsulation you need to work out what the interface that your base class provides needs to look like and ensure that it meets the needs of its clients (in this case the derived classes). That is your core design issue.

Comment: hmmm. i guess i kinda considered them to be more encapsulated when the only object that could manipulate there private members were behavior objects, but your right, that's still violating the ideal of encapsulation. The whole point of me trying to change up the abstraction system like so, was really just to make it safer/more straightforward for a user of the framework to add on to for their own game, but having public members like that, or unlimited friends,   would just allow the user to change something internally that they really shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, i think i'll rework the idea, maybe find a way to make it more airtight so to speak. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen through the years that there are 2 different points of view on friendship and how it affects encapsulation:

- It helps improve encapsulation by not making members public to everybody, and only making them accessible to a controlled subset of entities.
- It reduces encapsulation for the obvious classic reasons that the object should be self contained and should be the only entity to modify its internal parts, etc.

I tend to avoid using friendship and try to work around it. I prefer to encapsulate everything, not just to make it private, but to be able to change how its implemented internally without affecting the users of the class.  If you want a base class to be able to modify the attributes of a derived class, maybe you could consider using a [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern) design pattern. Whereby the base class orchestrates calling methods on the derived classes, and be sure to have generic, abstract manipulation methods defined in the base class.

As for making all the attributes of a class public "just in case", (sounds very dangerous) I think it would be better to start off making them all private, and consider making individual attributes public as the needs arise.

Comment: heh, this template method, (didn't know it was called that), was actually how i was approaching it in the first place, create a set of abstract functions that sort of kind of defined the behaviors of an object, and then define them in a derived class. the hangup was how, depending on the object, the abstract functions may have required a different amount of parameters. I'd show you an example of what i mean but i can't in comments...

Comment: Ya, Ive come across that problem too. The more varied the derived classes, the more difficult it becomes to keep it generic. Ive also seen projects with a class hierarchy that create a separate class hierarchy of types/data to help maintain the original base class interface generic.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis If your different classes share the same functions but need different arguments, can't you pass in a `struct` containing this information, and then verify the needed variables in the struct? That way, if you need to add some variable later, you just add it in the struct.

Comment: @Default, Yep, this is typically called a context. Depending on the needs, you could create a context container (possibly templatized) that stores the values internally in a map, with the key being the parameter name and the value being the object.

Comment: ughh, you know that vibe i was talking about in an earlier comment? definately getting it right now...  That would work, but it just seems to purposefully spite some of the reasons c++ was made the way it is ya know?

Comment: anyway, you did answer my question to the best of your ability and provided some useful insight, so the answer is yours :P

Comment: @FatalCatharsis, happy to help. C++ is quite powerful and generic, but it cant do everything, sometimes you have to work around certain parts of it :)

Comment: ain't that just the gosh darn truth :/

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad approach, Microsoft does it all the time and that's a good company, right? :) They even reserve certain blocks for future use.

Comment: @Default, Can I use the right to remain silent on that one? :)

Comment: @default passing in structures to functions is totally fine, and yes, microsoft does it quite a bit in win32, but i was talking about his mapping approach with the keys pointing to specified parameters. would totally work, but just seems to break the point of c++. Couldn't tell you that point, just a wild hunch i always get.